# Which file is needed by modern browsers with font-awesome?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have the following in my LESS/css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/Content/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('/Content/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/Content/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('/Content/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="fa-icon-"],
[class*=" fa-icon-"] {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

My application works and shows icons correctly but I am confused about which of these files will be used. I am using all modern browsers IE9, lastest Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Please see the image below]

We add font in different formats because every browser has its own way of rendering fonts so font in different formats are included.

Comment: But does this not make for some very large downloads? I'm trying to use http://www.icnfnt.com/#/ to cut down the size but trying this today it seems to no longer work :-(